# Socket Hang Up on Nodejitsu, What does it mean?

Tags: node.js, paas, nodejitsu

I'm getting socket hang up errors on Nodejitsu, what does it mean?

```
  error:   Error running command deploy
  error:   socket hang up
  error:   Error: socket hang up
  error:       at createHangUpError (http.js:1107:15)
  error:       at Socket.onend (http.js:1188:27)
  error:       at TCP.onread (net.js:369:26)
  info:    Nodejitsu not ok
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things that you might be doing that cause this:

- Make sure you're using port > 1024 (no sudo) Make sure your app is <
- 50mb disk space

If this doesn't work please either email support at nodejitsu or visit #nodejitsu at irc.freenode.org